# Find the longest ascending sub set in an un-ordered set

Tags: algorithm

Given an un-ordered set, such as: *1,2,3,4,0,5,6,7,-1,-2,-3;*

Find the longest ascending sub set in it.

The expected result for the above example set is : *1,2,3,4,5,6,7*

How to implement it?

Comment: Technically your question is incorrect. Since there's no order in sets, there may not be any "ascending"

Comment: I mean the *sub* set (*sub* sequence) is ordered.

Comment: Then it is an ordered sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is called `Longest increasing subsequence` and you can read about it [here](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Longest_Increasing_Subsequence).

Comment: Thanks. You lead me to the solution, and a great site. Thanks again!